# Hide a div on click with slow sliding to side animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, animation

**HTML**

```
<div id="two" />
<form >
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="button" id="twobtn" value="Pay" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="one" />
<form >
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="button" id="onebtn" value="Next"/>
</form>
</div>
```

The above html has two divs each having a form.When the page is loaded,only div id="one" should be shown.

After filling "one" , Next is clicked and the this form slides and fades away and div id="two" appears sliding.

i tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#two').hide();

$('#onebtn').on('click',function(){
    $('#one').hide('slow')
    $('#two').show('slow');
});
});

</script>
```

and this two divs are arranged one above the other.Can sliding transition from side can be made?Any help on how to achieve this?

I have a fiddle which is working http://jsfiddle.net/e6en9/  BUT WHEN I DO TRY IN MY WEBSITE,THE #TWO IS HIDDEN WHEN IT LOADS.WHEN I CLICK ON #ONEBTN IT HIDES THE FORM AND SHOW THE #TWO THEN AGAIN #TWO IS HIDDEN AND BACK TO HOW IT WAS WHEN LOADED.

Can someone help me with the jquery? A better jquery for this? And how to add slide from side animation?
Im new to jquery,this I have done reading the jquery doc..But cant make it perfect.Please help needed

Comment: Why did YOU ALL OF A SUDDEN START TYPING IN CAPITALS THEN go back to typing normally? Are you having a heart attack?

Comment: This may be your problem, http://jsfiddle.net/e6en9/1/. This `<div id="two" />` is not the correct way to close a tag. Instead do this `<div id="two">` for the opening tag.

Comment: What's the link to it on your website?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly LOL! simply :P

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Bahahaha...oh man you are a funny one lol

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, not a good way to treat new comers! -_- .. he is trying to tell you what the problem actually is, since he is a new comer he doesnot know the standards that are taken under consideration while posting..

Comment: Actually new to stackoverflow,thats why

Answer (score 1):

try this ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e6en9/3/))

```
$('#two').hide();
$('#onebtn').on('click',function(){
    $('#one').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('#two').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this sliding effect out:

```
$('#two').hide();
$('#onebtn').on('click',function(){
    $('#one').css({'position':'absolute', 'width':'380px'}).animate({"left":"100%"});
    $('#two').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Here is a link to an updated version of your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e6en9/4/

Edit:  Also in response to a comment made by Josh Powell, the opening tag for a div doesn't need a backslash.  Change your opening divs from  to